# How does addition function parameters appeared in scala?

Tags: function, scala, parameters, scalaz, function-parameter

I am reading example about [monad transformers](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monad+transformers.html) in scalaz. Here is a piece of code:

```
scala> def myName(step: String): Reader[String, String] = Reader {step + ", I am " + _}
myName: (step: String)scalaz.Reader[String,String]

scala> def localExample: Reader[String, (String, String, String)] = for {
         a <- myName("First")
         b <- myName("Second") >=> Reader { _ + "dy"}
         c <- myName("Third")
       } yield (a, b, c)
localExample: scalaz.Reader[String,(String, String, String)]

scala> localExample("Fred")
res0: (String, String, String) = (First, I am Fred,Second, I am Freddy,Third, I am Fred)
```

How does it happen, that `localExample` can take a parameter? Oo There is not any parameters list in definition 
`localExample: Reader[String, (String, String, String)]` just return type is specified. Also the same question about
  `myName` function, it also *has* more function parameters then mentioned in its definition.

Answer (score 0):

The key is in the return type that is specified, which is an instance of the Reader monad. Roughly, the reader monad is like a wrapper around a function from - in the case of `myName` - String to String, so it is a bit like a function defined as:

```
def myName(step: String): String => String
```

For `localExample`, the return type is now a "wrapper around a function from String to Triple of String" (quotes used because this is something of a simplified sense of what the Reader monad is).

In both cases, the return type is - sort of - a function that can take a (String) parameter with which to generate a final result, and it is this sort-of-a function that is taking the parameter passed to localExample in the call `localExample("Fred")`. Essentially like calling `localExample().apply("Fred")`.

There is more to monads like the Reader than just the above (which I'm not sure I feel expert enough to explain properly right now), but hopefully that's enough to answer your question.